# postgresql full join migrate the first two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two datasets like,

```
A   B
1   hello
2   hi
3   bye
```

And:

```
A   C
2   yo
3   gutentag
4   seeya
```

I'm using FULL JOIN on column A to have the both dataset in one table... But I got this:

```
A   A   B      C
1       hello
2   2   hi     yo  
3   3   bye    gutentag
    4          seeya
```

Instead of this I would like to get the two A column in one, liket this:

```
A    B       C
1    hello
2    hi      yo
3    bye     gutentag
4            seeya
```

I know this must be a basic question... But still, I can't solve it. :-)

My code is:

```
 SELECT dataset1.A, dataset2.A, dataset1.B, dataset2.B FROM dataset1
 JOIN dataset2
 ON (dataset1.A = dataset2.A);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select a, d1.b, d2.c
from
    d1
    full join
    d2 using (a);
```

Check the `using` clause: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM

> USING implies that only one of each pair of equivalent columns will be included in the join output